# resultless android app..calculator always gives 0

Tags: android

I develop an application where spinner contains add, sub, mul & div... but the result always gives zero. How I develop the app when button clicked the calculation solved depends upon the selected value of the spinner. The code is below::

```
public void Select(View view)
    {
        TextView txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        TextView txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        int x=Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString());
        int y=Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText().toString());

        Spinner spin1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String spin_value= spin1.getItemAtPosition(spin1.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

        if(spin_value=="Add")
        {
            int z=x+y;
            String addvalue=String.valueOf(z);
            Toast.makeText(this, addvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (spin_value=="Sub") 
        {
            int p=x-y;
            String subvalue=String.valueOf(p);
            Toast.makeText(this, subvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (spin_value=="Mul") 
        {
            int k=x*y;
            String mulvalue=String.valueOf(k);
            Toast.makeText(this, mulvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            int g=x/y;
            String divvalue=String.valueOf(g);
            Toast.makeText(this, divvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at it in a debugger?

Comment: Have you tried this in a debugger? My guess would be that you're falling through to the else clause and the division is always resulting in zero because it's performing integer division.

Comment: please paste the whole code this is unsufficient please declare and refer widgets in oncreate not onButton click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob Kaufman's comment is correct. You are falling through to your `else` statement by virtue of the comparisons you are making. To compare strings in Java you should use the `equals(Object o)` or `equalsIgnoreCase` methods, not `==` unless you want to determine if the Strings being compared are the same object.

On top of that, it's not really clear what is being returned by `getItemAtPosition` since we can't see what kind of `SpinnerAdapter` you are using. So, it may not even be appropriate to do the `String` comparisons in the first place.

Like, Bob, I suspect you are getting 0 because of integer division. If you put, say, 100 in txt1 and, say, 40, in txt2, I would guess your Toast would read `2`.